# Django domain is using example.com even after changing django_site domain and name

Tags: python, django

I'm using the registration/password_reset.html template which has

```
{{ domain }}
```

This always returns "example.com". I've changed my db django_site domain and name to something like "test.com". On local testing it works, but in a live environment it doesn't.

I'm really confused by this, I assume I'm missing something obvious - any suggestions?

Comment: i did
i've realised my issue too

Answer (score 0):

my problem was this :
each user could be assigned to different accounts, so i had to create an instance inside Sites for each account with the correct web address

hope this makes sense